# Error with only ECR image Back-off restarting failed container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, amazon-eks, amazon-ecr

I'm new with k8s and I've deployed a simple nginx deployment using eks and ecr. The problem only present when I'm using ecr image, it's not happens with nginx public image from docker hub.
Here is my deployment file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: *-ecr-registry
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          # image: nginx:latest
          image: *.dkr.ecr.*.amazonaws.com/nginx:dev
```

Here is output of a pod.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  12s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned *
  Normal   Pulled     10s (x2 over 12s)  kubelet            Container image * already present on machine
  Normal   Created    10s (x2 over 12s)  kubelet            Created container nginx
  Normal   Started    10s (x2 over 11s)  kubelet            Started container nginx
  Warning  BackOff    8s (x2 over 9s)    kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

Here is result log of the pod

```
exec /docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
```

I also ran the ecr image with docker in my local machine without any error.
Can someone give me some hints, how can I overcome this issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: Seeing the `.sh` with that is a bit mysterious, but plausible if your shebang line points to a shell that's arm64 but your cluster is amd64 or opposite

Comment: I just ssh to eks node, and run docker, it was ouput this `The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested`

Comment: I ran the image, and it showed `exec /usr/local/bin/node: exec format error`. Entry point of my image is just `["node", "ace", "serve",  "--watch" ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trying many ways, I realize that I'm using base-image `keymetrics/pm2:18-alpine` only supports amd64 kernel. Even I tried to rebuild my image in arm64, that doesn't not work in my work nodes with arm64 kernel type. So I see 2 ways to overcome this issue is:

- recreate my eks cluster using amd64 worker nodes.
- Or switch to other base-image like `node:18.14-alpine` that supports both arm64 and amd64 kernel.

Answer (score 2):

> The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the
> detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was
> requested

it's due to you have built the Docker image on an **ARM M1** chip either on Mac and try to run it on **AMD** or the opposite due to that it's throwing an error.

You can build the docker image again by passing ARG **--platform**

```
--platform linux/amd64
```

Or you can also set the Environment variable `export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64`

You can pass ARG with **FROM** in **Dockerfile** or while running command `docker build --platform`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node
```

**ARG** with build command

```
docker build -t <image-name> --platform linux/amd64
```

ref doc: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from

You can also **run** the image with docker like

```
docker run --platform linux/amd64 node
```

Comment: I've tried to build the images in amd64, but received `image was found but does not match the specified platform: wanted linux/arm64, actual: linux/amd64.`. So I rebuilt the image in arm64, and run docker with arm64, it returned `exec /usr/local/bin/node: exec format error`

Comment: my machine to build docker is using `[x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e]`, it's a macbook intel chip. And worker node is using `ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64`

Comment: if you are on `x86_64 ` use the `linux/x86_64` you have to specify the platform as per requirement i have shared above for ref as not sure you are on which platform and running on which one.

Comment: there is `--platform=linux/x86-64` and `--platform=linux/x86_64` so build accordingly on which you are planning to run image. also you are using the `--no-cache` while building the docker image.

Comment: Yeah, I built images in arm64, and I inspected the image in worker node by `docker image inspect` it showed `"Architecture": "arm64"`. In worker node I run `uname -m` => `aarch64`. Its the same kernel architecture, but I ran docker run the image, it still showed `exec /usr/local/bin/node: exec format error`. What am I doing wrong :((